# Format date with 3 digit year

Tags: c#

I am using a program that has a configuration file like this:

```
<text string="{0:yyy}">
    <param type="date" />
</text>
```

That is translated here:

```
String.Format(textNode.attr(string),arrayOfObjFromParamChildNodes)
```

My problem is in this case the year is not 3 digit, but always 1993 or 2003, but I want write 993 and 003.

Is there a way to trim the first character without changing the parser?

Comment: `yyy` is the format for a _minimum_ of 3 digits, not exactly 3 digits.

Comment: [yyy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#yyySpecifier)  doens't *trim*, it returns a *minimum* of 3 digits. The docs explain that it returns a minimum of 3 digits with zero padding

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why 3 digits? There is no format that will return exactly 3 digits, so you'll have to either create a custom date parser or modify the current one

Comment: As we and our children keep moving away from the 20thentury this may well become the normal year format; at least I have predicted it in the late 90s ;-)

Comment: @TaW I hope not...

Answer (score 1):

My client wants the year in 3 digit, it is odd I know... 
at I added something like:

```
If (format.Contains("yyy") && !format.Contains("yyyy"))
foreach date in args replace it with d.Value.AddYears(d.Value.Year % 1000 -d.Value.Year)
```

Personally I think for coherency `yyy` should write always only 3 digit, but it is a big world.

Comment: As a developer isn't it your responsibility to bring common sense to the table and explain why a 3 digit year is an odd choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression which takes last 3 symbols of the string.

```
    string pattern = @"(.{3})\s*$";
    var result = Regex.Match(year,pattern);
```

.net fiddle [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kQEbYq)

Answer (score 0):

The client probably needs something like FASAT is using:
3 digits year format means: 1st digit - century and last 2 - 2 digit year, so 2019 should be 219, 1997 - 197 etc